# Create consecutive labels for boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, cut

I want to set the labels of a binned boxplot automatically based on the cut-intervals. The data-bins are created by applying `pd.cut()` on a data frame. The list of the `pd.cut` is specified manually (see `cut` list), but I want the histogram labels to be set automatically based on the cut-list.

How do I convert the `cut` list to a label list using code?
The code below gives me a division as:

`['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100']`

However I would like it to be:

`['0-20', '21-40', '41-60', '61-80', '81-100']`

**Code:**

```
cut = [0,20,40,60,80,100]

for i, p in enumerate(zip(cut, cut[1:])): 
    label.append('{}-{}'.format(cut[i], cut[i + 1]))
print(label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do the following:

```
cut = [0,20,40,60,80,100]
label = []

for i, p in enumerate(zip(cut, cut[1:])):
    label.append('{}-{}'.format(p[0] + 1 if p[0] != 0 else p[0], p[1]))
```

It will give you:

```
label
['0-20', '21-40', '41-60', '61-80', '81-100']
```

`p` will be 2 values (`cut[i]` and `cut[i+1]`) and you wish to add 1 to the first position unless it's the beginning (this is handled by the following condition in the code above `...1 if p[0] != 0 else p[0]`).